# Loop to create date value from list of dates for every ID in list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two lists, one of dates and the second of user IDs.
I need to create a further two lists where for each date in the date list, every user id gets a value created for them.

See attached image, where cols C/D are my original columns and F/G are my desired outcome.
[image]
A solution either in google sheets through a formula or though scripts would be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a formula way to do it (assuming same columns):

In F2 (Don't forget to format the column as Date):

```
=ArrayFormula(HLOOKUP("Date",C:C,ArrayFormula(INT(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(C2:C)*COUNTA(D2:D),1,0)/COUNTA(D2:D)+2))))
```

In G2:

```
=ArrayFormula(HLOOKUP("ID",D:D,ArrayFormula(MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(C2:C)*COUNTA(D2:D),1,0),COUNTA(D2:D))+2)))
```